# "Not an answer" declined because it looks like an answer

Tags: discussion, flags, not-an-answer

I feel like this must have been addressed somewhere before, but I can't find it.

I had a bit of trouble deciding what to do with an answer the other day and I wanted to get further opinion/ clarification.

The answer has since been edited so I'll just illustrate here rather than link.

---

*Question code - which isn't working (example)*

```
Sub HelloWorld()
    MessageBox "Hello world"
End Sub
```

*Answer suggestion*

```
MessageBox "Hello world"
```

---

It's clearly *exactly the same* code that the user has -- not to mention it's a one liner (but that's not really the point)

I flagged it as "Not an answer" because for all intents and purposes, it's not an answer. That said, I was almost certain it would be declined because it looks plenty like an answer. I wondered if I should have flagged as "In need of moderator intervention" and explained that it clearly isn't an answer. I was reluctant to use that option because I feel like "Not an answer" describes the issue well.

From what I've read I can see that we are encouraged to downvote bad answers, but where do you draw the line between someone who has attempted to answer the question and done badly and someone who has simply copy and pasted the same code the user had?

What is the right way to deal with answers like this? Just downvote?

**Update**

In response to the possible duplicate with [When to flag an answer as "not an answer"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-not-an-answer). I checked this link thoroughly before posting and I was still in two minds. The main factor for me is whether I should regard copy and pasted code as a "bad answer" or not. For me, it's not an answer at all. At this point the further debate between NAA/Moderator intervention is relevant -- which is not covered by the possible duplicate either.

Comment: well it is attempting to answer. In a completely terrible and wrong way. But it is trying to answer. "Not an answer" is for PURE gibberish, or a question. if any stretch of the imagination lets you go "mmmm yeah it tries", then it is not a valid NAA flag.

Comment: Your only declined flag this year was on a question from early January. If you're talking about your flag from the last 24 hours, it was disputed by 3 community members in review. It'd be a lot easier if you'd make the post link public so we can talk specifics without using moderator-only information.

Comment: @Patrice Copying a portion of the question and re-posting it sure seems like it's Not An Answer to me.  Repeating the question isn't even an attempted answer.

Comment: @Undo, thanks for pointing that out - I didn't notice the difference between declined and disputed. I'm more interested in what to do in this scenario in future, rather than dissecting this specific case.

Comment: Just for the sake of argument, I can think of cases where the answer in your example _would_ actually fix the problem. I'm not saying that's true in this case, but it is possible that the OP had added something to their code that kept it from working (like pointlessly wrapping something in a function that was never called) and the code in the answer could just be the part from the question that would actually work. The answerer should definitely also include some explanation if that's what they thought the problem was, though. Without the explanation, who knows what they were thinking.

Comment: I'd still like to see the actual code and more importantly the context. Can you give us the link to it? I'm an adult, I can handle an edit history.

Comment: Why are you still keeping it secret? Got something to hide?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

> I wondered if I should have flagged as "In need of moderator intervention" and explained that it clearly isn't an answer.

You wonder correctly.  If you come across a post that is Not An Answer, but is not an answer for a reason that isn't immediately apparent at a glance, it's appropriate to use a custom flag and explain why you feel the post isn't an answer, in this case, because it's just copying the code from the question.

You're right to be hesitant to not use a canned flag when available, but it's appropriate to use a custom flag when a more detailed explanation of why the post is problematic is needed, which is usually the case when the larger context of the post is relevant (in this case, that the code is exactly the code from the question, which isn't going to be apparent to someone handling normal NAA flags).

Now, doing this should be fairly rare.  If you think that half of the non-answers you come across need a mod flag, then odds are something is off (either you're flagging posts that are answers as NAA, or the answers aren't as hard to identify as NAA as you think), but it's perfectly fine to, every once in a while, come across a post that needs a bit of outside context that would be useful for those handling it.

Comment: Nice answer. Also in this particular case I think  downvote would be enough and no need of flag  to moderators.